# how to understand the function of "fill_decode_caches" in h264_mvpred.h

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I don't understand the availability of some boundaries， for example:

`if(!(top_type & type_mask)){
      sl->topleft_samples_available = 0xB3FF;
      sl->top_samples_available = 0x33FF;
      .....`

what mean of 0xB3FF ?